# What method should be used to perform one task multiple times in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, asynchronous, azure-worker-roles

Im have this simple task

```
void DoWork(string job)
```

That shoud bu performed many times in parrallel on **Azure Worker Role**.
I have these options:

- multi Asynchronous calls to DoWork

  ```
  while(true) {DoWorkDelegate.BeginInvoke(...);}
  ```
- Allocate by myself many threds

  ```
  while(true) {Thread t = new Thread( DoWork);
               t.Start();}
  ```
- Thread Pool

In terms of utilizations what is the recommanded method?

Comment: Use `Task`s instead of directly messing with threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that this example is over simplified. In the examples shows a new thread would be spun up for each iteration in the loop. While I completely agree with @DanielMann to use TPL instead of threads, adding

```
while (true) {
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());
}
```

would still spin up a lot of threads. Make sure there is a test for work to do outside of spinning up the threads like

```
while (true) {
  job = FetchJobFromQueue();
  if( job != null ){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(job));
  }
  else {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Note the sleep time to keep from pegging the processor on an empty loop.

On a somewhat related note, take a look at this MSDN [article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a-CRRqNYFDo8J%3ablogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/01/14/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events.aspx%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) for proper handling of that while(true) loop for exit conditions.